# How to concatenate two unique arrays and remove 'nan'?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Using the [Pokemon Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/abcsds/pokemon), I want to extract all the unique types in columns: "Type 1" & "Type 2" and print them out after. So far, I've been able to concatenate the unique values from both columns together into an array. Now I'm having trouble removing 'nan' from the array.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/edwinandrew/Documents/Datasets/Pokemon.csv")
type_class1 = df['Type 1'].unique()
type_class2 = df['Type 2'].unique()
all_types = np.concatenate((type_class1, type_class2))
print(all_types)
```

Output:

```
['Grass' 'Fire' 'Water' 'Bug' 'Normal' 'Poison' 'Electric' 'Ground'
 'Fairy' 'Fighting' 'Psychic' 'Rock' 'Ghost' 'Ice' 'Dragon' 'Dark' 'Steel'
 'Flying' 'Poison' nan 'Flying' 'Dragon' 'Ground' 'Fairy' 'Grass'
 'Fighting' 'Psychic' 'Steel' 'Ice' 'Rock' 'Dark' 'Water' 'Electric'
 'Fire' 'Ghost' 'Bug' 'Normal']
```

I tried using `x = x[~numpy.isnan(x)]` to see if that would remove the nan value but I got an error. What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: _I tried using x = x[~numpy.isnan(x)] to see if that would remove the nan value but I got an error._ Please share all relevant code, as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `dropna`

```
type_class1 = df['Type 1'].dropna().unique()
type_class2 = df['Type 2'].dropna().unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

type_class1 = df['Type 1'].dropna().unique()
type_class2 = df['Type 2'].dropna().unique()

Or use fillna() Method

Answer (score 0):

#### `stack` + `dropna`

Create one Series, drop the missing values and call unique.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Type_1': ['Grass', 'Fire', 'Steel', 'Ghost'],
                   'Type_2': [np.NaN, 'Water', 'Fire', 'Grass']})

df[['Type_1', 'Type_2']].stack().dropna().unique()
#array(['Grass', 'Fire', 'Water', 'Steel', 'Ghost'], dtype=object)
```